# Can the vertex angle of an isosceles triangle be found without the law of cosines (no calculator)?

Tags: geometry, triangles

If we know three sides of an isosceles triangle, can we find the measure of the angles without using a calculator (that means no law of Cosines/Sines).

Comment: Depends on the meaning of find. One can use the definition of sine.

Answer (score 0):

Call the sides of the triangle lengths $a$, $a$, and $b$. Drawing a line of symmetry through the triangle lets us divide the triangle into two right triangles. Hence we can calculate $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\frac{b}{2}}{a}=\frac{b}{2a}$$
where $\theta$ is the repeated angle in the triangle. This tells us the angles of the triangle are $\theta$, $\theta$, and $90-2\theta$, where 
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{b}{2a}).$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  We can use the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

That is, choose two sides of unequal lengths $a$ and $b$.  Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denote the measures of their respective opposite angles$.  Then we have:

$$\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{a} = \frac{\sin(\beta)}{b}$$

If $a < b$, then $2\alpha + \beta = 180^\circ$ since the triangle is isosceles.  From here, we have $\beta = 180^\circ - 2\alpha$.  Plug this into the above, and we have an equation with a single unknown.

Comment: I meant more in the spirit of not using a calculator when I excluded using the law of Cosines, and this method would still require a calculator.

Comment: Oh I understand, sorry about that.  I'll leave my answer up anyhow since others might get something out of it.